# Error when trying to run any Cypress test

Tags: javascript, testing, installation, plugins, cypress

I've installed Cypress according to the cypress docs. After opening Cypress and selecting a test to run, I instantly get the following error:

```
**Title:** Error running plugin
```

**Message:** The following error was thrown by a plugin. We stopped running your tests because a plugin crashed. Please check your plugins file (`C:\Users\metin\Desktop\Programming\School\Typescript\From JS to TS\cypress\plugins\index.js`)

**Stack trace:**

```
Error: The following error was thrown by a plugin. We stopped running your tests because a plugin crashed. Please check your plugins file (`C:\Users\metin\Desktop\Programming\School\Typescript\From JS to TS\cypress\plugins\index.js`)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\metin\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.1.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\errors.js:1043:15)
    at EventEmitter.handleError (C:\Users\metin\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.1.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\index.js:189:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\metin\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.1.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\util.js:19:22)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:920:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

I've been googling for a few hours and I'm looking for help on how to resolve this issue!

Comment: I'm facing the same error. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: I resolved it by downgrading my node from v17 to v14( I chose 14 because of other dependencies). Try downgrading your node if it's v17.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall Nodejs
2. Download the Nodejs (Recommended For Most Users) version from the link:
   https://nodejs.org/en/
3. Install the downloaded Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues
in my case, this issue was related to my bitbucket.yml.file, I changed: max-time:(set time for running your tests) in my job, and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cucumber then review your step files in search of misspelling keywords or case sensitive typos like `wHEN` or `thEn`